# Call methods stored in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

i'm looking at the examples posted here: for calling methods from a dictionary,
could anyone suggest something a bit more real world?

Calling a method that has some more and complex parameters, I tried to adjust the examples here but sorry, not experienced enough.

This was posted but how about calling a method like this?

```
private static void Method1(string[] curr, string[] prev, int counter)
{
    var a1 = curr[5];
    Console.WriteLine(a1);
}
```

Sorry if question is a bit "tony the pony" :-)

prev posted example below

```
    private static void Method1(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    private static void Method2(int x)
    {
    }

    private static void Method3(int x)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Action<int>> methods = new Dictionary<int, Action<int>>();
        methods.Add(1, Method1);
        methods.Add(2,  Method2);
        methods.Add(3, Method3);

        (methods[1])(1);
    }
```

Comment: You would just use a different overload of Action.  Eg, Action<string[], string[], int> for your example.

Comment: Are all methods in dictionary supposed to have same or different signatures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question...
You can call `Method1` from dictionary as well like in your example:

```
var methods = new Dictionary<int, Action<string[], string[], int>>();
methods.Add(1, Method1);

methods[1](new[]{"Hello"}, new[]{"World"}, 1);
```

You just create dictionary with another overload of [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

If your `Method1` looks like:

```
static int Method1(string[] curr, string[] prev, int counter)
{
    return 4;
}
```

Then you should use [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549430%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate:

```
var methods = new Dictionary<int, Func<string[], string[], int, int>>();
methods.Add(1, Method1);

var result = methods[1](new[]{"Hello"}, new[]{"World"}, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad, that gave me no red_lines on VS.  So if I want to call a method which returns something? i.e. private static int { blah blah} ?

Comment: Great Vlad, thats it.  Im using this to replace a large case/switch statement. Many Thanks